# Как распознать изображение средствами Qt?

Tags: нейронные-сети, qimage, изображения, qt, c++

кто читает это!
Интересует такой вопрос:

> Как разбить изображение на пиксели и обработать каждый из них? Или как
>   получить доступ к каждому определенному пикселю этого изображения?

В целом стоит задача распознать черно-белую картинку размером 16X32, формата png/jpeg. И реализовать это нужно в QtCreator'e.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Что говорит мануал Qt? Неужели у них нет штатных средств для доступа к пикселю с координатами Х,У ?

Answer (score 2):

Загружайте картинку в QImage, а у него есть метод [pixel(int x, int y)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#pixel-2), который возвращает QRgb - а с него можно получить данные о цвете пикселя. width и height соответственно возвратят размеры картинки.